# React-router-dom v6 not rendering components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

[Console throwing errors when I used React router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxNhX.png)

[Have followed the router-dom v6 syntax still not able to render components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMGP5.png)

Comment: Please edit your post to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the relevant code you've an issue working with along with the error message, both formatted to be readable. Images of code and error messages should only be included if they add additional information that can't be expressed in textual form. From what I see of the errors it seems you've not imported your routed components correctly. I notice in the image that the `Home`, `About`, and `Profile` files indicate they haven't been saved.

Answer (score 1):

the console errors state that you did a default import for the Home, About, and Profile components, verify if you did a default or named export for  those three components

Comment: yes I did default import for Home,Profile and about Component

Comment: check your components if you have a named export change it to a default export

Comment: It is default export

Answer (score 0):

This error appear when you have V6 of react-router-dom. V6 have many groundbreaking change so try to read official documentation check this out:https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/

Check this for more details

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70075248/11729240